# Is this vector identity correct?

Tags: vectors

I cannot remember where I have seen this formula. But it looks like this:
$$
(\vec A \cdot \vec B) \vec C = (\vec C \otimes \vec A) \vec B
$$
I think it is a strange formula since I cannot find it in any textbook I have read. So is it correct? How would one show it?

Comment: The left side is a vector, the right side is a scalar (assuming you meant a dot product there). Check your formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bra-ket notation can help to see this. By this way you will have LHS
$$
\big(\langle A| B\rangle\big)|C\rangle = |C\rangle \big(\langle A| B\rangle\big)\quad,
$$
since $\langle A| B\rangle$ is a scalar. Then
$$
 |C\rangle \big(\langle A| B\rangle \big)= \big(|C\rangle \langle A|\big) |B\rangle\quad,
$$
since vectors and co-vectors are associative. Then you will have
$$
\big(|C\rangle \langle A|\big) |B\rangle = \big(\vec C \otimes \vec A\big) \vec B
$$ 
as you want.

Comment: So we must think of  $|C> <A|$ as a transformation matrix, right?

Comment: @SaksithJaksri Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of
$$
{\bf a}\cdot ({\bf b}\times {\bf c})= {\bf b}\cdot ({\bf c}\times {\bf a})={\bf c}\cdot ({\bf a}\times {\bf b}).
$$

Comment: I think not, I quite familiar with  this formula.

Comment: @SaksithJaksri  Yes. I like the BraKet answer much better.